# XML DOM Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, dom

If I'm having an in-memory DOM of:

```
<root xmlns="NS1" xmlns:a="NSA">
    <outer>
        <a:inner>Text</a:inner>
    </outer>
</root>
```

and have a reference to the outer node.

After I call `outer.setAttributeNS(XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI, "xmlns:a", "NSB")` and traverse to inner it looks like the DOM specs say that `inner.getNamespaceURI()` still returns NSA.

Somebody knows how to get from `inner` to NSB?

Comment: fixed typo of course I meant </a:inner> ;-)

Comment: `NS1` and `NSA` is are not valid URIs. Also it's not clear to which DOM implementation you refer to. As in your answer `getPrefix()` does not look as being part of any W3C DOM.

Comment: (1) NS1 and NSA are of course just examples to shorten the code. (2) W3C DOM level 2 has attribute prefix, in Java this converts to a getPrefix() method, see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, sometimes it hits you just after pressing the "Ask Question" button ...

`inner.lookupNamespaceURI(inner.getPrefix())` looks to be the way to go.

Comment: I have to say that any time `inner.lookupNamespaceURI(inner.getPrefix()).equals(inner.getNamespaceURI())` returns false, you are opening yourself up to world of pain.

Comment: True word. However, it's not up to me, if I'm going to implement this part of the DOM specs or not ;-)

Comment: Sure. It's a bit odd that DOM lets you do that at all. If you want to change the namespace of elements, you should really create a new element in the new namespace and replace the old element with the new one. XSLT is an efficient way of doing that across a complete document.